# Installing Intel OneAPI Basekit in Windows Container

Tags: windows, docker, containers, intel-oneapi

I'm trying to install an Intel OneAPI BaseKit inside of a windows container using docker for windows. However, when I try to install (inside the dockerfile or directly in the windows container), I get the following error:

```
cmd /S /C w_BaseKit_p_2021.3.0.3221_offline.exe -s -a --silent --eula accept' returned a non-zero code: 1001
```

I've tried to troubleshoot this but I cannot seem to find what the non-zero code 1001 refers to. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please try posting your query in the Intel [community forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Developer-Software-Forums/ct-p/developer-software-) forums for better assistance.